# difference between updating window location and pushing route to react router

Tags: reactjs, web, react-router

I needed to change the route of my application. I'm using react and there are two ways to do. 1) router.push(pathObject) and 2) window.location = pathName

which is the right way to do and why?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to react-route. `history.push`  is useful in your case when it comes to navigating.